# Specify aspect ratio / equal scales on Vegalite plot

Tags: d3.js, vega, vega-lite, altair

On an Vegalite xy chart, how do I specify the data aspect ratio to 1? In other words, I want the same scaling from data to plot units for both x and y axes. In Matplotlib this is achieved with [matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_aspect('equal')](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_aspect.html). How would I modify the following spec snippet?

```
{
  "width": 500,
  "height": 500
  "mark": {"type": "line", "point": {"size": 0}},
  "encoding": {
    "x": {"field": "y", "type": "quantitative"},
    "y": {"field": "x", "type": "quantitative"},
    "color": {
      "field": "run",
      "type": "nominal",
      "scale": {"scheme": "magma"}
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Vega-lite and altair don't have an aspect argument or set_aspect method like in matplotlib. I had a same question earlier this week and this is the answer that I got from one of the devs;

> It’s definitely possible to change the width/height of a figure, which
>   is almost the same thing See
>   https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/aggregate_bar_chart.html for an
>   example

So as long as your width and height have the same value then by default the aspect will also be equal.

Comment: Thanks. However, I don't agree with the dev that it is "almost the same thing". The set_aspect method sets the aspect ratio of the data (i.e. the ratio of the domains of the x and y scales), and this can be very different from the aspect ratio of the figure itself (the ratio of the ranges of the x and y scales). These two ratios can and should be able to vary independently. For geometric data, such as positions, it can severely distort the interpretation and scaling if the data aspect ratio is not 1.